# Learning dictionaries with multiple attributes - How to edit when a key has more than one?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to edit (add, subtract, and stuff like that) to this dictionary:

```
data = {'Altri': [10000, 4.3910, 4.3910],
        'BCP': [10000, 0.2312, 0.2312],
        'Corticeira Amorim': [10000, 12.2500, 12.2500],
        'CTT': [10000, 5.5480, 5.5480],
        'EDP': [10000, 3.2840, 3.2840],
        'EDP Renovaveis': [10000, 6.9910, 6.9910],
        'Galp Energia': [10000, 13.7850, 13.7850],
        'Ibersol': [10000, 14.9000, 14.9000],
        'Jeronimo Martins': [10000, 17.5600, 17.5600],
        'Mota-Engil': [10000, 2.7340, 2.7340],
        'NOS': [10000, 5.5150, 5.5150],
        'Novabase': [10000, 3.2390, 3.2390],
        'Pharol': [10000, 0.2690, 0.2690],
        'REN': [10000, 2.8680, 2.8680],
        'Semapa': [10000, 16.7000, 16.7000],
        'Sonae Capital': [10000, 0.8740, 0.8740],
        'Sonae SGPS': [10000, 0.9260, 0.9260],
        'Navigator': [10000, 4.0720, 4.0720],
        'Montepio UP': [10000, 0.7470, 0.7470]}
```

my logic: `BANK NAME - BALANCE - BUY VALUE - SELL VALUE`

What I am trying to do:

So I know that I can do stuff like

```
print(data["Altri"])
```

But how can I edit the buy and sell values?
Can someone show me how to do like a print of the sell value?
I keep googling stuff but it's rather hard to find stuff for this kind of dictionary.

Comment: it would probably be a lot easier (and safer) to have the value as a dictionary, rather than a list. for example: `'Altri': {'balance': 10000, 'buy': 4.3910, 'sell': 4.3910},` and then yould edit them with `data['Altri']['balance'] = 15000` or something else.

Comment: You can edit by simply typing `data['Altri']=new_value`, for example `data['Altri']=[10000,5,5.5]`. Adding new elements is really the same: `data['new']=[newBalance,newBuy,newSell]`...

Comment: If you want the sell value from `Altri` then `print(data['Altri'][2])`.

Comment: Do you actually have control over that data, or do you receive it in this format?

Comment: Just in case you would not have control over it: `{key:dict(zip(['balance', 'buy', 'sell'], values)) for key, values in data.items()}` - would create a dict of dicts out of a dict of lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are working with a list, you access the values by index (keep in mind that indexes start with 0. To print the sell value, you need to access the 3rd index of the list, `2`:

`print data['Altri'][2]`

And to change the value, you would do the same:

`data['Altri'][2] = 6`

it would probably be a lot easier (and safer) to have the value as a dictionary, rather than a list. for example: `'Altri': {'balance': 10000, 'buy': 4.3910, 'sell': 4.3910}`, and then yould edit them with `data['Altri']['sell'] = 6` or something else.

Comment: was just about to comment on your comment! thats exacly what i will do! it makes the code a lot easier to work with and read! thanks a lot

Comment: lists are best used when you need a list of values. in situations like yours, where you are storing individual values that represent something unique, it's always best to use a dictionary. it makes accessing and viewing code so much easier, as well as leaving less room for mistakes.